# Encode MediaRecorder stream in PCM format for AWS transcribe

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, getusermedia, mediarecorder, amazon-transcribe

So I'm trying to use AWS transcribe medical but unable to achieve as AWS transcribe medical require "pcm" encoded audio data. I tried multiple custom function but no luck.
I want to use something like MediaRecorder start method because i want to send data in chunks in real time.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  TranscribeStreamingClient,
  StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const mediaRecorder = useRef(null);
  const audioChunks = useRef([]);
  const transcribeClient = useRef(null);
  const client = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
    region: "region",
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
      secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
    },
  });

  const handleMicClick = () => {
    if (!isRecording) {
      startRecording();
    } else {
      stopRecording();
    }
  };

  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorder.current.addEventListener(
        "dataavailable",
        handleDataAvailable
      );
      mediaRecorder.current.start(1000);
      setIsRecording(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error starting recording: ", error);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    mediaRecorder.current.stop();
    setIsRecording(false);
    transcribeClient.current.destroy();
    transcribeClient.current = null;
  };

  const handleDataAvailable = (event) => {
    audioChunks.current.push(event.data);
    if (transcribeClient.current === null) {
      transcribeClient.current = client;
    }
    sendAudio(event.data);
  };

  const sendAudio = async (audioData) => {
    const input = {
      LanguageCode: "en-US",
      MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
      MediaEncoding: "pcm", // required
      Specialty: "PRIMARYCARE", // required
      Type: "CONVERSATION", // required
      AudioStream: audioData, // -> This needs to be in pcm format
    };

    const command = new StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionCommand(input);
    const response = await client.send(command);
    console.log("Response: ", response.TranscriptResultStream);

    for await (const event of response.TranscriptResultStream) {
      if (event.TranscriptEvent) {
        const message = event.TranscriptEvent;
        // Get multiple possible results
        const results = event.TranscriptEvent.Transcript.Results;
        // Print all the possible transcripts
        results.map((result) => {
          (result.Alternatives || []).map((alternative) => {
            const transcript = alternative.Items.map(
              (item) => item.Content
            ).join(" ");
            console.log("something is happening", transcript);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <button onClick={handleMicClick}>
          {isRecording ? "Stop" : "Record"}
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If there is any package which will do the job then please mention.